# Using CAS as application gateway and OpenID IdP for Idenity

Tags: openid, cas

I currently have a group of webapps which all use CAS for Authentication. CAS is backed by an LDAP Identity store. What I would like to do is allow uses to sign in using an OpenId provider. Is it possible for CAS to create an authentication context off an OpenId Identity?

I have seen the CAS has some support for OpenId but the documentation is light.

Answer (score -2):

That's of course possible and used quite often. In the company I'm working for we used exactly the approach from the [documentation](https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASUM/OpenID) to get it up and running

Comment: This answer is talking about using CAS as an OpenId *provider*. The question is how to use CAS as an OpenId client/gateway.

Comment: So what he's looking for is something like that https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASUM/Configuration+for+the+OAuth+client+support+in+CAS+server+version+%3E%3D+3.5.1